# Признаться (?) я жду этого с нетерпением

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вводные-слова

Какой нужен знак?

`Признаться, я жду этого с нетерпением.`

`Признаться — я жду этого с нетерпением.`

Я думаю, нужно тире, так как подразумевается ***Если** признаться*, а если нет союза *если*, то в БСП ставим тире.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ставим запятую:
***Признаться, я жду этого с нетерпением.***

[**Грамота.ру**](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_633&layout=item):

> **ПРИЗНАТЬСЯ / ПРИЗНАЮСЬ,** *вводное слово*
>
> То же, что «говоря откровенно, по правде говоря».

[**Знаки препинания при вводных словах, сочетаниях слов и предложениях**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127)
(ПАС под ред. Лопатина):

> **§ 91.** Вводные слова и сочетания слов выделяются или отделяются **запятыми:**
> <...>
> **Примечание 1.** Вводные слова и сочетания слов:
> <...>
> **е)** указывают на экспрессивный характер высказывания: <...> *правду говоря, правду сказать, **признаться, признаюсь*** <...>

***Признаться,** я совсем-то поглубже зайти побоялся — вдруг он где притаился?* (Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, 1964)
*Потом, **надо признаться,** я стал реже ездить туда* (Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок, 1975-1977).
***Признаться,** я уже решил взять вас к себе, дать тему* (Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого, 2000).